# Syncing highlights made on kindle with kindle for Mac

Tags: kindle, calibre, annotations, sync

I have a Kindle Paperwhite, on which I've transferred books from my Mac using calibre. While reading on my kindle, I've made some notes and highlights. How do I go about syncing these highlights and notes with the Kindle app on my Mac?

Note I'm not talking about just extracting the notes and highlights from 'My clippings.txt'. Rather, I want to sync highlights across books. I want my highlights and notes show up when I open the book on Kindle for Mac.

Thanks!